# response checker in a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, tee

I have following response checker in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

test_fn()
{
WARNFILE=$1
echo
echo "--- BEGIN ---"
cat ${WARNFILE}
echo "--- END ---"
echo

while true; do
    read -r -n 1 -p "Continue? [y/n]: " REPLY
    case $REPLY in
      [yY]) break ;;
      [nNqQ]) echo;exit ;;
      *) printf "\033[31m%s\033[0m\n" " invalid input: ${REPLY}"
    esac
done
}

test_fn /tmp/warning
```

it works fine...

```
$ ./test.sh

--- BEGIN ---
test warning
--- END ---

Continue? [y/n]: a invalid input: a
Continue? [y/n]: s invalid input: s
Continue? [y/n]: d invalid input: d
Continue? [y/n]: w invalid input: w
Continue? [y/n]: s invalid input: s
Continue? [y/n]: q
$
```

...until I change line:

```
test_fn /tmp/warning
```

with line:

```
test_fn /tmp/warning | tee -a /tmp/logfile
```

then, it scrambles lines:

```
$ ./test.sh

--- BEGIN ---
test warning
Continue? [y/n]: --- END ---

aContinue? [y/n]:  invalid input: a
sContinue? [y/n]:  invalid input: s
dContinue? [y/n]:  invalid input: d
fContinue? [y/n]:  invalid input: f
q
$
```

Anyone could please tell why it works so?

Comment: It's because `read` is writing the prompt to `stderr` but you are only redirecting `stdout` to `tee` I think; that results in the original `stderr` getting intermixed with the `tee`d `stdout`. Try `test_fn /tmp/warning 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/logfile`

Comment: @steeldriver, indeed, you are absolutely right, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a comment to an answer:

`read -p` writes the prompt to stderr; in order to get the results in-line for `tee`, pipe the function's stderr to stdout before the `tee` with:

```
test_fn /tmp/warning 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/logfile
```

To demonstrate `read`'s behavior:

```
$ read -p "my prompt: " >/dev/null
my prompt: hi
$ read -p "my prompt: " 2>/dev/null
hi
```